# Prevent Jekyll from splitting paragraphs when including an HTML container

Tags: include, markdown, jekyll, liquid

On a markdown page I would like to `{% include %}` a piece of template into a paragraph, which contains an HTML container.

### Markdown

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur {% include myContainer.html %} sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

### myContainer.html

```
<div>
hello
</div>
```

There should actually be an additional first and blank line in the file (which unfortunately doesn't get displayed here).

### output:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
<div>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<p>sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
```

Jekyll automatically splits the text into two paragraphs.

#### desired output:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur <div>
  <p>hello</p>
</div> sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
```

#### _config.yml

```
markdown: kramdown

kramdown:
  parse_block_html: true
  input: GFM
```

How can I include the container as child of the text's paragraph without splitting it in two?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: <div> elements should not be nested inside <p> elements. What I assume is happening is that the parser is seeing the open <div> tag and closing the open <p> tag for you to stay within the HTML spec.

Comment: @BryanSchuetz Thanks, I see!
My problem becomes a lot more complicated then, I guess. I would like to inject multiple additional information blocks to a very long text, which should be shown next to the corresponding text (while not breaking the text flow) and also be close to the corresponding text in the code. I guess that's a whole new topic.

Answer (score 0):

A [`<div>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-div-element) tag is a block level element. You cannot have block level elements inside a [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-p-element) tag. Therefore, (as mentioned in a comment) the parser is seeing the `<div>` and breaking your paragraph into two. By the way, even if the Markdown parser did not do that, the Browser would actually see it that way. Any block level element automatically closes an open `<p>` tag. Of course, the second paragraph would not be opened with a `<p>` tag in that scenario, so the browser could behave unpredictably. In other words, be glad the Markdown parser does the right thing here.

If you want to include information blocks in a paragraph without breaking the text flow, then you want the inline equivalent; the [`<span>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-span-element). If you want any specific styling, you can create some CSS to apply to `<span>`s. You might even want to assign a class to each span for more fine grained control.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Waylan. `<span>` does indeed work and is probably what I'm going to use.
But maybe my question was a bit misleading, as I was actually trying to use `<aside>` for text annotations and tried to simplify it here as a more general question. So if I wanted to use `<aside>` (which splits the paragraph in the same way) I obviously had to do it outside the paragraph. I tried to avoid it in order keep the annotation close to the corresponding text passage. But I guess in order to achieve this, I have sacrifice tag semantics?

Comment: But still, when using `<span>` in conjunction with a few tags like `{% if %}`,`{% assign %}` or `{% capture %}` it's rather difficult to find a constellation that does not split the paragraph. It would be great to know more about the rules behind it.

Comment: The `<aside>` tag is block level. You can only use inline level tags. Also if your template tags (`{% if %}`, etc.) are on a line by themselves, after template processing the text will contain blank lines in their place. Those blank lines will be seen as paragraph breaks by Markdown.

Comment: Thanks @Waylan! So I'm using `<span>`s now and would like to get rid of the line breaks. Is there any way of disabling Markdown parsing for includes? I know it's possible to use `*.html` extension for possible for posts and pages. But for includes this does unfortunately not work.

Comment: Sorry, you will need to write your templates as inline code. Little to no line breaks. Yes, it is less readable, but it is the only way to ensure paragraphs don't get broken up. Personally, I would abandon using templates in my Markdown. But that is just my personal opinion.